# Confusing terms in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, terminology

I am confused with the following terms. Please elaborate on what each of the following means:

1. Run time
2. execution time
3. dynamically creation
4. virtual machine

Comment: These are not ASP.Net-specific terms. In light of your previous question, Novice, I *strongly* recommend just Googling these terms, or searching for them on Wikipedia. People have written excellent, detailed articles on each of these.

Comment: This sounds a lot like someone's homework assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Msdn or Google for these terms.
http://msdn.microsoft.com

For example:
runtime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479328.aspx